# How do I optimise a filter loop for Cortex-M3?

Tags: performance, loops, assembly, arm, thumb

I just need to alter the code so that it does the same basic function but more optimised, basically I think the filter loop is the main piece of code that can be changed as I feel there are too many instructions in there, but don't know where to start with it. I am working with the Cortex M3 and Thumb 2.

I have tried tampering with the filter loop, so that I could add the previous number stored in the register and divide that by 8, but I do not know how to really execute that.

```
; Perform in-place filtering of data supplied in memory
; the filter to be applied is a non-recursive filter of the form
; y[0] = x[-2]/8 + x[-1]/8 + x[0]/4 + x[1]/8 + x[2]/8

  ; set up the exception addresses
  THUMB
  AREA RESET, CODE, READONLY
  EXPORT __Vectors
  EXPORT Reset_Handler
__Vectors 
  DCD 0x00180000     ; top of the stack 
  DCD Reset_Handler  ; reset vector - where the program starts

num_words EQU (end_source-source)/4  ; number of input values
filter_length EQU 5  ; number of filter taps (values)

  AREA 2a_Code, CODE, READONLY
Reset_Handler
  ENTRY
  ; set up the filter parameters
  LDR r0,=source        ; point to the start of the area of memory holding inputs
  MOV r1,#num_words     ; get the number of input values
  MOV r2,#filter_length ; get the number of filter taps
  LDR r3,=dest          ; point to the start of the area of memory holding outputs

  ; find out how many times the filter needs to be applied
  SUBS r4,r1,r2   ; find the number of applications of the filter needed, less 1
  BMI exit        ; give up if there is insufficient data for any filtering

  ; apply the filter  
filter_loop
  LDMIA r0,{r5-r9}     ; get the next 5 data values to be filtered
  ADD r5,r5,r9         ; sum x[-2] with x[2]
  ADD r6,r6,r8         ; sum x[-1] with x[1]
  ADD r9,r5,r6         ; sum x[-2]+x[2] with x[-1]+x[1]
  ADD r7,r7,r9,LSR #1  ; sum x[0] with (x[-2]+x[2]+x[-1]+x[1])/2
  MOV r7,r7,LSR #2     ; form (x[0] + (x[-2]+x[-1]+x[1]+x[2])/2)/4
  STR r7,[r3],#4       ; save calculated filtered value, move to next output data item
  ADD r0,r0,#4         ; move to start of next 5 input data values
  SUBS r4,r4,#1        ; move on to next set of 5 inputs 
  BPL filter_loop      ; continue until last set of 5 inputs reached

  ; execute an endless loop once done 
exit    
  B exit

  AREA 2a_ROData, DATA, READONLY
source  ; some saw tooth data to filter - should blunt the sharp edges
  DCD 0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
  DCD 0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
  DCD 0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
  DCD 0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
end_source

  AREA 2a_RWData, DATA, READWRITE
dest  ; copy to this area of memory
  SPACE end_source-source
end_dest
  END
  END
```

I expect there to be a more efficient way to run the code, weather that reduces the overall size of the code or speeds up the execution time of the cycles, as long as it does the same thing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can have a look at that later.  Consider using a C compiler if you have trouble optimising this yourself.

Comment: Do you need to use registers outside the r0..r7 range that allows short 16-bit encodings?  Also, `adds r0, #4` saves code size vs. `add`, in Thumb mode.  See the Thumb code-size section of my answer on [How do I reduce execution time and number of cycles for a factorial loop? And/or code-size?](//stackoverflow.com/q/55599285) .  Look at the disassembly for your code and look for 32-bit instructions, and check why they're 32-bit, and look for a way to make them 16-bit.  This is just super-basic Thumb optimization that you should always be doing before asking others to look at saving code size.

Comment: did you try starting with C and compare and maybe tune that.  Try a couple of compilers or versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For code-size, try to only use registers r0..r7 which can be used in short 16-bit encodings.

Also, versions of instructions with flag-setting often have 16-bit encodings when the non-flag-setting version requires 32-bit.  e.g.

- `adds r0, #4` is 16-bit vs. 32-bit `add r0, #4`
- `movs r7,r7,LSR #2` is 16-bit vs. 32-bit `MOV r7,r7,LSR #2`
- `movs r2,#filter_length` is 16-bit vs. 32-bit `MOV r2,#filter_length`.  (non-tiny immediates like `#88` still need a 32-bit Thumb2 `mov`)
- `stmia   r3!, {r5}` (with write-back) is 16-bit vs. 32-bit `str  r7, [r3], #4` with post-increment.

See the Thumb code-size section of my answer on your earlier question: [How do I reduce execution time and number of cycles for a factorial loop? And/or code-size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55599285).  Look at the disassembly for your code and look for 32-bit instructions, and check why they're 32-bit, and look for a way to make them 16-bit. This is just super-basic Thumb optimization that you can always do.

---

`r1` and `r2` aren't even used inside your loop, and r4 = `r1-r2` is an assemble-time constant that you're computing at runtime with 3 instructions...  So that's obviously insane vs. `movs r4, #num_words - filter_length`.

If those are supposed to be inputs that aren't known at assemble time for your real code (maybe the same function is sometimes used on different inputs?), then reuse the registers that are "dead" after calculating a loop counter.  It's kind of clunky that you accept pointers in r0 and r3, so you then have `r2` and `r4-r7` free if you use `r1` for the loop counter, or `r1-r2` and `r5-r7` free if you use `r4`.

I chose to use `r1` for the loop counter.  This is disassembly from my version (`arm-none-eabi-gcc -g -c -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 arm-filter.S  && arm-none-eabi-objdump -drwC arm-filter.o`)

```
@@ Saving code size without any other changes

00000000 <function>:
   0:   480a            ldr     r0, [pc, #40]   ; (2c <exit+0x4>)
   2:   f05f 0158       movs.w  r1, #88 ; 0x58
   6:   2205            movs    r2, #5
   8:   4b09            ldr     r3, [pc, #36]   ; (30 <exit+0x8>)
   a:   1a89            subs    r1, r1, r2
   c:   d40c            bmi.n   28 <exit>

0000000e <filter_loop>:
   e:   e890 00f4       ldmia.w r0, {r2, r4, r5, r6, r7}
  12:   443a            add     r2, r7
  14:   4434            add     r4, r6
  16:   4414            add     r4, r2
  18:   eb15 0554       adds.w  r5, r5, r4, lsr #1
  1c:   08ad            lsrs    r5, r5, #2
  1e:   c320            stmia   r3!, {r5}
  20:   3004            adds    r0, #4
  22:   3901            subs    r1, #1
  24:   d5f3            bpl.n   e <filter_loop>

00000026 <exit>:
  26:   e7fe            b.n     26 <exit>
```

Cortex-M3 doesn't have NEON, but there is data reuse between outputs.  With unrolling, we can definitely reuse the load results, and some of the "inner" `add` results.  Maybe with a sliding window to subtract the word that's no longer part of the total and add in the new one.

But with the middle element being "special", we have two 2-element windows on either side, **unless we have enough spare bits at the top to add `x[0]` twice and then right shift by 3 without overflowing.**  Then you don't even need to unroll, just load 1 element / adjust sliding window and recalc the middle / store 1 element.

(My first version of this answer was based on a misunderstanding of the code.  I might update with a speed optimization later, but for now editing to remove wrong stuff.)

Comment: Note that instead of `str r5, [r3], #4` you should use `stmia r3!, {r5}` as the encoding is shorter.  The performance should be the same.  You wrote `stmia r3, {r5}` without the bang, which is why you get weird disassembly.

Comment: @fuz: oh crap, I forgot that write-back was optional, so my analysis is totally wrong.  I thought `ldmia` was moving `r0` by 5 words, oops.  (I thought that was weird, now it makes a lot more sense.)