# DCX and Carry flag

Tags: assembly, intel-8080

I am learning 8080 assembly as part of a course that I am undertaking. I am referring to Intel 8080-8085 Assembly Language Programming manual (dated 1977).

In Chapter 3 Instruction Set of the manual, I see the following description in relation to DCX:

> DCX decrements the contents of the specified register pair by one. DCX
>   affects none of the condition flags.

The associated example says:

> Assume that the H and L registers contain the address 9800H when the
>   instruction DCX H is executed. DCX considers the contents of the two
>   registers to be a single 16-bit value and therefore performs a borrow
>   from the H register to produce the value 97FFH.

I tried the math on my own using two's complement addition and there is definitely a carry generated.

So my question is: Is carry bit set only in the case of arithmetic operations?

TIA

PV

Comment: There is a typo in your example: `DCX H` should be `DCX HL`. As per the answer by @AlexeyFrunze - the answer to your question is in the documentation that you quote. Do not confuse the "carry generation" in arithmetical sense and the Carry flag in a CPU, never **assume** the latter always follows the former. There are CPU architectures where the flags are never set (by default) by arithmetical/logical ops, you have to explicitly "ask" for them to be set (eg. ARM).

Comment: @tum_: and equally importantly, on ARM the carry flag for subtraction is set if there's *no* borrow.  Opposite of x86 (and presumably 8080) where it's a borrow flag for subtract.  And of course on x86 `inc`/`dec` don't modify CF, only the other flags.  `add`/`sub` set CF.  So yes, definitely you have to check on a per-instruction basis how they set flags.

Comment: @PeterCordes True. There was one of those impromptu contests for the most efficient ARM Asm snippet, on google.groups I think, where I first learned (from a guy who apparently was from the ARM C compiler dev team, I bet he's on SO too) that EOR and the like do not affect the Carry flag. Being from z80 world I assumed it to be cleared until I actually checked the ARM reference. Good lesson.

Comment: @tum_ fun fact: in ARM's Thumb mode, the short 16-bit encodings for most instructions are for the flag-setting version.  (i.e. `s` suffix on the mnemonic) 
 Surprisingly, [that includes `movs` for moving an immediate to a register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55734308/how-do-i-optimise-a-filter-loop-for-cortex-m3/55736431#55736431).  That's not so crazy for reg-reg moves when you remember that `movs` with a shift for the source operand will set flags based on the shift/rotate, but it's weird for immediates.  But yeah, most RISCs that have a flags reg at all have flag-setting optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the particular CPU aside and just considering binary arithmetic, no borrow is generated when subtracting 1 from 9800H. A carry is generated when adding 0FFFF to 9800H, though. In both cases you get 97FFH in the 16 least significant bits of the result.

Irrespective of the design choices put into the CPU you need to simply follow the documentation, e.g. [this document, MCS®-80/85 FAMILY USER'S MANUAL](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/intel/MCS80/MCS80_85_Users_Manual_Jan83.pdf).

It says in 5.6.1 Data Transfer Group:

> Condition flags are not affected by any instruction in this group.

5.6.2 Arithmetic Group:

> Unless indicated otherwise, all instructions in this group affect the Zero, Sign, Parity, Carry, and Auxiliary Carry flags according to the standard rules.

Similarly in 5.6.3 Logical Group:

> Unless indicated otherwise, all instructions in this group affect the Zero, Sign, Parity, Auxiliary Carry, and Carry flags according to the standard rules.

5.6.4 Branch Group:

> Condition flags are not affected by any instruction in this group.

5.6.5 Stack, I/O, and Machine Control Group:

> Unless otherwise specified, condition flags are not affected by any Instructions in this group.

You need to memorize how common instructions affect flags. You may compile a simple cheat sheet or, perhaps, find one made by someone else (some assembly books had those for the programmer's convenience).

If you're interested in why some instructions don't affect flags or some affect them in a particular way, it depends. The reasons can be different, depending on the particular instruction: cheaper circuitry, easier to program common problems, compatibility with earlier designs or just simply carrying forward what had worked well without giving it much additional thought.

Answer (score 2):

`DCX H` is certainly an arithmetic instruction, but 16-bit increment and decrement instructions do not change any flags on i8080, even though 8-bit ones, such as `DCR H` and `DCR L`, do. You can find further details on this in the Intel 8080 Microcomputer Systems Users Manual, available here:

http://www.nj7p.info/Manuals/PDFs/Intel/9800153B.pdf

Also, looking at internals of Z80 emulators may help. Here's the relevant snippets to compare from my implementation:

```cpp
    void on_dec_rp(regp rp) {
        self().on_set_regp(rp, dec16(self().on_get_regp(rp)));
    }
```

[DCX rp](https://github.com/kosarev/z80/blob/01f37043e1e9cc0d6032822ffcd3ab2601b2aeec/z80.h#L2127)

```cpp
    void on_dec_r(reg r) {
        fast_u8 n = self().on_get_reg(r);
        fast_u8 f = self().on_get_f();
        fast_u8 hf = (n & 0xf) > 0 ? hf_mask : 0;
        n = dec8(n);
        f = (f & (cf_mask | yf_mask | xf_mask | nf_mask)) |
                (n & sf_mask) | zf_ari(n) | hf | pf_log(n);
        self().on_set_reg(r, n);
        self().on_set_f(f);
    }
```

[DCR r](https://github.com/kosarev/z80/blob/01f37043e1e9cc0d6032822ffcd3ab2601b2aeec/z80.h#L2469)